# Xcode can not build React Native Project, Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods, command-line-tool

My project is not able to build with Xcode after my Xcode Command Line Tools & MacOS upgraded.

Running `npx react-native run-ios` works fine, can wake up the simulator and debug.

When build on Xcode, I receive this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___isOSVersionAtLeast", referenced from:
      -[GDTCORApplication init] in libGoogleDataTransport.a(GDTCORPlatform.o)
      ___28-[GDTCORStorage storeEvent:]_block_invoke.22 in libGoogleDataTransport.a(GDTCORStorage.o)
      -[GDTCORStorage appWillForeground:] in libGoogleDataTransport.a(GDTCORStorage.o)
      ___35-[GDTCORStorage appWillBackground:]_block_invoke in libGoogleDataTransport.a(GDTCORStorage.o)
      -[GDTCORStorage appWillTerminate:] in libGoogleDataTransport.a(GDTCORStorage.o)
      +[GULSecureCoding unarchivedObjectOfClasses:fromData:error:] in libGoogleUtilities.a(GULSecureCoding.o)
      +[GULSecureCoding archivedDataWithRootObject:error:] in libGoogleUtilities.a(GULSecureCoding.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang-7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23183

Comment: Awesome, that partly solved my problem now, now when i use `npm run ios`, it ONLY worked on Toolchain Swift 5.2.1 (some dependencies were built using carthage); Vice versa, Xcode can only build with the newest Toolchain.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, this problem is caused by using an old toolchain.

Recent release of Firebase require at least Xcode 10.3. More details in https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5219